# How do I get list of all S3 Buckets with given prefix using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am writing a Terraform script to setup an event notification on multiple S3 buckets which are starting with given prefix.

For example I want to setup notification for bucket starting with `finance-data`. With help of [aws_s3_bucket](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket) datasource, we can configure a multiple S3 buckets which are already present and later we can use them in [aws_s3_bucket_notification](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_notification) resource. Example:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "source_bucket" {
    # set of buckets on which event notification will be set
    # finance-data-1 and finance-data-2 are actual bucket id
    for_each = toset(["finance-data-1", "finance-data-2"])
    bucket = each.value
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification_to_lambda" {
    for_each = data.aws_s3_bucket.source_bucket

    bucket = each.value.id

    lambda_function {
        lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.s3_event_lambda.arn
        events = [
            "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
            "s3:ObjectRemoved:*"
        ]
    }
}
```

In [aws_s3_bucket](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket) datasource, I am not able to find an option to give a prefix of the bucket and instead I have to enter bucket-id for all the buckets. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This would be a feature request for the provider, or you could PR it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to achieve this?

No there is not. You have to explicitly specify buckets that you want.